# Convention of writing percentage range

Tags: numbers, academia, scientific-language

I am writing to inquire the convention of writing the following percentage range in academic writing:

> We reduce the extra cost from 99.9% to 12%--24% (depending on different configuration schemes).

Or

> We reduce the extra cost from 99.9% to 12--24% (depending on different configuration schemes).

Maybe I ask which one is more proper in academic writing? I tried to search in Google Scholar but it seems that both usage can be found (although the second one seems more frequent).

Comment: You can look this up by Googling for example `percentage range in apa style` or `percentage range in mla style`.

Comment: With 2 dashes, it looks like a range from twelve to negative 24.

Comment: If your word processor allows it, you should consider using an [en dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) instead of hyphens to indicate a range of numbers. This eliminates the ambiguity between a second hyphen and a negative sign on the second number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm the following usage is recommended in `apa style`:

> Ranges of percentages may be presented using the percent
>   sign only once (10–20%, 20 to 30%)